# Model the setuptime for one Agent with diffrent Agent Names in a service block

Tags: model, simulation, anylogic

i have used a service block for my machine. i want to implement my setup time in it. So the setup time and the processing time will be a common time.

I would like to write a function for my delay time in the service block. How can I write the function that it gives me the following output: If the predecessor is agent.Name "A" and then agent.Name "B" comes then XX delay time. If the predecessor is agent.Name "A" and then agent.Name "C" comes then XX delay time.... and so on. Name is a Parameter in the Agent

Maybe i can use a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put a variable of type String `predecessorName` next to the service block
2. create a function `getDelayTime` that returns a double and takes 2 input arguments of type String: `nameCurrentAgent` and `namePredecessor`
3. in the function, compare as you need, for example:

   ```
   if (nameCurrentAgent.equals("A") && namePredecessor.equals("B") {
        return 12.;
    } else if ...
   ```
4. in the service block's delay code block, you call `getDelayTime(agent.Name, predecessorName)`
5. in the service block's "on at exit" code block, update `predecessorName = agent.Name` for the next agent

Comment: Thanks, it work! But if the first Agent dont have a Predecessor, how can i write this? Because null is not a String

Comment: Additional if-check: `if (predecessorName == null) return 0.` or similar. Please upvote replies that where helpful, helps future users with similar problems, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: But i write this:
```
if (nameCurrentAgent.equals("Oberteil_Stange") && PredecessorName == null) {
 return 4.47;
```
I get: PredecessorName cannot be be resolved to a variable.

Comment: Java is case-sensitive so `PredecessorName` is not the same as `predecessorName`. Follow my instructions precisely and it works :) Also, start using code-complete and do not type words yourself (see the help on this :) )